# ondeviceorientation implementation under Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, orientation

I am currently developing an HTML 5 application for smartphones, using the ondeviceorientation event ; in order to obtain a smartphone 3-dimensional orientation.

I found out that the rotation data emitted by this event contains more or less noise, depending on the web browser used.
I tested my application under Android and had the most stable results using Firefox.
The results with the Android default browser were noisy.

Is there any Firefox hacker out there who knows if some filtering is applyed to
the ondeviceorientation event under Mozilla Firefox? I am surprised that i have better results from Firefox than the default Android browser and would really like to understand what is going on under this event.

Thanks a lot for your help